# C programming to control GPIO LED

Tags: c, embedded, gpio

I have a hardware where I need to turn on LED connected in  GPIO( Looking at hardware specs, GPIO BCBUSB0 is connected to LED) to show that software is running fine inside it. If for some reason software is not running , then LED should turn off or become red.

Now , I thought I should set up a watchdog or something which sends signal to Led in regular interval to show status that software is running. if for some reason LEd does not receive signal with particular interval it should turn off.

I am quite comfortable in using C language, but have no idea about programming GPIO to turn on/off LED. Any advice or suggestion will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you running on?  What kind of environment?

Comment: its Linux operating system( Ubuntu) kernal version 2.6. I am accessing the hardware through ethernet port. I read  few documents and I think I need to send HIGH and LOW signal in regualr interval to show software is running.  But I dont know how to start? As stated LED is connected at BCBUSB0on GPIO( and on pdf it has num written 48) so do u guys think I need to shift bit till 48 and then manipulate it ?

Comment: It's a very good guess to shift the 1-bit and write it. To know for sure, you need to look at the schematic. You might want to read the PIO first, set/clear your LED bit, then write it back. That way, you won't set/clear PIO outputs inadvertently. BTW, does that PIO ***really*** have 48 output pins? Or do you want to set/clear bits 4 and 5 (48 decimal = 0x30)?

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for reply, Looking at pdf  and diagram that I have  its a FT2232H chip with GPIO hand written marking starts from BCBUS0 and number 48 is written. I am very novice in electronics and has no clue how to begin the things

Comment: Hi Pete on closer inspection to IC circuit, I have found GPIO is  8 bits and start from ( I Guess pin number 48 not sure as in pdf it has marking of 48 then next is 52 then 53 til 59) all together there is 8 pins for GPIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FT2232H is a USB-to-UART converter chip.  A quick glance at the [datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232H.pdf) shows that it can be placed in a bit-bang mode which is what you are apparently trying to do.  If you read section 4.10 of the datasheet, it references [AN2232-02, “Bit Mode Functions for the FT2232”](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN2232C-02_FT2232CBitMode.pdf) which claims to have the details and some examples of how to do this.

You say you're communicating with the hardware via Ethernet but that doesn't sound right (or at least is only part of the story).  Most likely, the FT2232H is connected to a processor (possibly your host machine) via USB.  To toggle the GPIO pin, you'll need to configure the FT2232H so that it operates in bit-bang mode.  Once you've figured out how to do that you'll need to send commands over USB in order to toggle BCBUSB0.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sean, your suggestion helped me a lot in understanding the FTDI chip.  At the moment my code is working fine in standalone application but when I intergrate it into baseline code , it just doesnt work. I am looking into it . And Thanks again